# mapping of a point from a sphere into UV plane

Tags: raytracing, projections, uv-mapping

I am reading the book **An introduction to raytracing by Eric Haines** and it mentions an algorithm to map a point from a sphere into a UV plane, it calls it **Inverse Spherical Mapping** (page 49). I googled a lot about this term and could not find a single piece of information regarding it.

Given the normal to a point on a sphere (**Sn**) and the sphere's north pole unit vector (**Sp**) and a unit vector from the sphere's origin to the sphere's equator (**Se**) as shown below

[image]

Using the right-hand coordinates system. It drives the following formula for v and u

[image]

I understand the **Dot product** yields **cosine** of an angle between two vectors, but why **-Sn**? from the picture **v** starts from the south pole and varies towards the north, but why the **minus sign**? (the book mentions **v** varies from **-Sp** to **+Sp** )

As for **u** I am not sure why we do divide by **sine phi**. and why do we take the cross product to determine **u**? (I know the **cross-product** gives us a perpendicular vector to both, which is probably used to know on which side the normal is, but I am not sure exactly how that worked as the **equator** is changing, so it can be both right and left)

Comment: For the -Sn it has been sorted, the problem I had was I was using the left-hand coordinates system and the book strictly stated it was using right-hand coordinates (maybe my habit got me to keep using the left-hand coordinates) 
However, I still don't know how the cross-product is used here, or why the division with sin(phi)

Comment: $(\vec A \times\vec B) \cdot \vec C$ is the "scalar triple" product, the sign flips under inversion.

Comment: hmm that was a little cryptic the scalar triple product can be rewritten as $\left \| \vec A \times \vec B \right \| \left \| \vec C \right \| sin(\theta)$

Comment: Thanks, I got it in the end, it seems to be a standard conversion from the spherical coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC this and some other texture mapping/projection techniques are discussed in [Watt & Watt's *Advanced Animation and Rendering Techniques*](https://archive.org/details/advanced-animation-and-rendering-techniques-1992)
Skip forward to around page 180.  FWIW that has a reference to a 1946 (!) document but I haven't gone looking to see if it's the original source :)

[image: Spherical mapping excerpt from AAaRT]

Though 'old', *Watt & Watt* is well worth buying IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, someone pointed me to the spherical coordinates system and it is the exact match. [as shown here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/TISphericalCoords.aspx)
The only difference is that, this assumes **phi** is actually calculated from the z-axis towards xy-plane, however in the picture I shared in the question **V** varies from south pole to north pole, for that we take the negative of the north pole in V calculation.